# Possibility of choosing imagenet_utils.preprocess_input modes from ImageDataGenerator

Tags: tensorflow, image-processing, keras, conv-neural-network

There is a preprocessing technique where we can preprocess image with respect to ImageNet dataset using the following:

```
from keras.applications import imagenet_utils
imagenet_utils.preprocess_input(image, mode='caffe')
```

You see I choose `mode='caffe'`. In fact, there are three modes as explained by `Keras.applications` API:

```
mode: One of "caffe", "tf" or "torch".
  - caffe: will convert the images from RGB to BGR,
      then will zero-center each color channel with
      respect to the ImageNet dataset,
      without scaling.
  - tf: will scale pixels between -1 and 1,
      sample-wise.
  - torch: will scale pixels between 0 and 1 and then
      will normalize each channel with respect to the
      ImageNet dataset.
```

Since I use `ImageDataGenerator` from `keras.preprocessing.image` in my code, is there a workaround to allow such modes to be set from `ImageDataGenerator` since these three modes are applied with respect to the ImageNet dataset?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ImageDataGenerator has a `preprocessing_function` argument in which you can pass a function to be applied to the images. To adapt the mode, you can do the following:

```py
from functools import partial
from keras.applications import imagenet_utils

imagenet_caffe_preprocessing_function = partial(imagenet_utils.preprocess_input, mode="caffe")

data_generator = ImageDataGenerator(preprocess_function=imagenet_caffe_preprocessing_function, ...)
```